# How to correct flow warning: destructuring (Missing annotation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm writing a small React Native app and I'm trying to use Flow, but I can't really get a proper tutorial about it anywhere.

I keep getting the error: `destructuring (Missing annotation)` about the `({ station })` in the 1st line of this code:

```
const StationDetail = ({ station }) => {
  const {
    code,
    label,
  } = station;
```

`station` is a *json response* and `code` and `label` are `strings` inside that *json*.

How do I fix the error/warning?

Comment: If station is a JSON response, maybe you must write `{'code': code, 'label': label}` no ?

Comment: With `flow` I don't know, but in plain JS React Native is fine that way.

Comment: It is because of the scope of ES6 type annotations restriction. You can just specify the type of the const just like `...const {code:string, label:string}...`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would write this as

```
type StationType = {
  code: String,
  label: String,
}

function StationDetail({ station } : {station : StationType}) => {
  const {
    code,
    label,
} = station;
```

It's necessary to declare the type of the object parameter that the function accepts.

Answer (score 10):

I tried your example and got `No errors!`, because Flow doesn't require type annotations on private functions.

If instead I add an `export` like this:

```
// @flow
export const StationDetail = ({ station }) => {
  const {
    code,
    label,
  } = station;
  return code + label;
};
```

I get the following error. (Which I assume is close enough to what you are seeing.)

```
Error: 41443242.js:2
  2: export const StationDetail = ({ station }) => {
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ destructuring. Missing annotation


Found 1 error
```

You can solve that in at least two ways. The better way is to add a type annotation for the function argument. For example:

```
export const StationDetail =
  ({ station }: { station: { code: number, label: string } }) =>
```

or

```
export const StationDetail =
  ({ station }: {| station: {| code: string, label: string |} |}) =>
```

or even

```
type Code = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;
type Radio ={|
  station: {| code: Code, label: string |},
  signalStrength: number,
  volume: number,
  isMuted: bool,
|};
export const StationDetail = ({ station }: Radio) =>
  ...
```

if you want to make sure the `StationDetail` is always called with a proper Radio object even though the current implementation only looks at the `station` field.

The other alternative is to change the first comment to `// @flow weak` and let Flow infer the argument type on it's own. That is Less Good™ because it makes it easier to accidentally change your public API and makes your actual intentions less clear.

Answer (score 0):

In order the object destructuring work  you should provide the appropriate object structures on the right side of the assignment. In this particular case `{station}` as the function argument (left side of the assignment) should be fed by something like `{station:{code: "stg", label:"stg"}}`. Make sure you are calling the `StationDetail` function with an appropriate object as argument like.

```js
var StationDetail = ({ station }) => {
  var {code, label} = station;
  console.log(code,label);
},
    data = {station: {code: 10, label:"name"}};

StationDetail(data);
```

Comment: The error continues to be the same this way. But the function is already called that way you say, I just call the component in another function with : `<StationDetail key={station.code} station={station} />`, where `station` here is the json response.