# Assign value types to destructured objects with flow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, flowtype

I want to extract the values foo and bar from an object. With typical ES6 syntax it should look like this :

```
let {foo, bar} = object;
```

I am using flow to integrate data typing in my project. I am actually getting this error for every keys i try to extract from the object :

```
Property foo is missing in mixed [1].
Property bar is missing in mixed [1].
```

I am guessing flow needs a type to those foo and bar variables but i can't assign any type since it will consider it as a value of the key. 
Any help would be helpfull

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correct flow warning: destructuring (Missing annotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443242/how-to-correct-flow-warning-destructuring-missing-annotation)

Comment: yep I guess it is and i should declare the object values types from outside first.